# Getting MySQL Schemas for All Tables

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to download/backup the schema of an entire MySQL database. Is there a way to easily do this? I haven't had much luck using a wildcard, but that could be an error on my part.

Answer (score 20):

I would use the --no-data option to mysqldump to dump the schema and not table data.

```
 mysqldump --no-data [db_name] -u[user] -p[password] > schemafile.sql
```

Answer (score 15):

Login as root, then

```
show databases; # lists all databases
use information_schema; # connect to the mysql schema
show tables;   
select * from tables;
```

Everything you need is in the information_schema schema.  If all you want to do is backup the db, use the builtin dump/restore capabilities.

Answer (score 6):

How about using mysqldump?

```
mysqldump -u root -p[password] [db_name] > backupfile.sql
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see all the tables from a schema in MySQL then you can use

```
SHOW TABLES FROM MY_DATABASE;
```

Comment: This question is specifically about getting the schemas (think "create table" output) of all of the tables. Not simply listing the tables.