# MySQL Select All Fields of ALL Tables which have records Order By Table

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

I am in need of a query to select all Tables, **field names**, from all tables where table has data.

I would like to be able to have Table, Field where given table has data rows in my result set.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445552/getting-mysql-schemas-for-all-tables) ....
[Getting MySQL Schemas for All Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445552/getting-mysql-schemas-for-all-tables)

and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-can-i-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them) ...
[How can I find all the tables in MySQL with specific column names in them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193780/how-can-i-find-all-the-tables-in-mysql-with-specific-column-names-in-them)

I believe I need something similar to

```
SELECT COL.COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS COL
WHERE COL.TABLE_NAME IN

(SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%tbl%')

....    
Having Count > 0
```

Comment: I don't know what dynamic table assignment has to do with the question. 
You state This question already has answers here: 
Dynamic table name at sql statement 
Nothing to do with the question. Tushar ha sit right .

Comment: I agree too.
Do we have to flag moderator for `someone marking it as a duplicate of a totally different question` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query shall give you the tables from 'your_schema_name' along with it's row count

```
select
  table_Name, SUM(table_rows)
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_schema_name'
group by table_Name;
```

To Simply select all tables which have atleast one record; Please use below query :

```
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_schema_name'
and table_rows > 0;
```

Also;
To view fields (columns) from all the tables which have data;
You can use following query :

```
select table_Name, column_name
from information_schema.columns 
where table_schema = 'your_schema_name'
and table_name in (
       select table_name 
       from information_schema.tables
       where table_schema = 'your_schema_name' 
       and table_rows > 0
   );
```

OR; You can also write the above query using (inner) join as :

```
select
  i.table_Name, 
  i.column_name
from
  information_schema.columns i 
  inner join information_schema.tables t 
  on i.table_name= t.table_Name
where
  i.table_schema = 'your_schema_name' 
  and t.table_schema = 'your_schema_name' 
  and t.table_rows > 0;
```

Comment: I was playing around with the thing SELECT  *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb'
    AND TABLE_NAME IN (SELECT  TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' 
    AND TABLE_ROWS > 0)
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
I will mark yours as answer!